# Corona "Certificate Not Installed" even though it is

Tags: ios, certificate, coronasdk, provisioning-profile

I realize this question comes up a lot, but there is no one solution that has seemed to work for anyone.

I am working on developing an app for iOS and recently had to transfer my app to another developer account. My first account was an individual account where I was "Agent," and now the new account (corporate I think) has me listed as "Agent."

I created the certificates like I have always done, downloaded them, and placed them in my keychain. Everything said it was in order. I then created the app ID and re-entered all of the devices into the devices column. I moved on to the provisioning profiles, and again everything worked well. I downloaded them and imported them into Xcode, and when I go under settings and look under the account, it all looks in order.

Then when I attempt to build in corona, it tells me "Certificate Not Installed." Even though I had created the certificate on that device.

A possibility is that having 2 apple dev accounts signed in at once was confusing, so I logged out of my other, and, not surprisingly lost my ability to build for those either. I could still not build for iOS.

I have tried restarting my computer several times, and deleting everything and starting from scratch. I have tried creating the certificates a variety of ways and billions of combinations. I even tried using my other computer - although it also had dev set up for my other account.

Am I missing something crucial here? I don't have another computer to start over on if that is what it takes, but I guess I could clear one...

I greatly appreciate any suggestions!!

Answer (score 2):

More specifically, for Starter and Basic subscribers, on OS-X you will need to download a new latest public build (2014.2393a).  For Pro and Enterprise subscribers, you will need 2014.2405 or later.

Starter and Basic subscribers may have to add something to their build.settings for now due to another change Apple instituted this week.  See:  http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/08/21/ios-building-issue

Answer (score 0):

After some more hours of digging, I finally found a solution. Apparently apple changed some things in their newest releases, specific to their provisioning profiles and something in Xcode.

Corona Forums had this thread that solved ALL of my problems: http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/50226-certificate-not-installed-cant-build-for-ios/page-2#entry260678

To summarize the forum - you need to install a new build of corona that solves the problem: https://developer.coronalabs.com/downloads/coronasdk

I hope my struggles have helped someone :)